# Query runs fine when executed on DB directly , but when executed using php it fails

Tags: php, mysql

Query runs fine when executed on DB directly, but when executed using PHP it fails.

```
SELECT  count(A.age),LEFT(C.name, 10) FROM game A  INNER JOIN `dixit` C ON (A.roll=C.roll) WHERE LEFT(C.added, 10)>='09-05-2013' group by LEFT(C.added, 10) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/total.txt';
```

In PHP:

```
$query_t = "
    SELECT  count(A.age),LEFT(C.name, 10) 
    FROM game A  
    INNER JOIN `dixit` C ON (A.roll=C.roll) 
    WHERE LEFT(C.added, 10)>='09-05-2013' 
    GROUP BY LEFT(C.added, 10) 
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/total.txt'
";

mysql_query($query_t) or die ("query failed");
```

Comment: For starters, use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/mysql_error) instead of `"query failed"`

Comment: Might not be the query then. Make sure you're connecting to the DB successfully first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't use `INTO OUTFILE` statement in PHP. [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) says:

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you
>   very quickly dump a table to a text file on the server machine. If you
>   want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server
>   host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is
>   no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file
>   system.

I think, their suggestion below can help you.

> However, if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote
>   machine, you can instead use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT
>   ..." > file_name to generate the file on the client host.

If not, maybe there will be other way, but I'm sure you need to dig into that way.